# how can remove duplicate value from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When i execute the code it show the error list index out of range

```
array = [1, 22, 22, 3, 14, 14, 24, 5]
j = 0
i = 0
list1 = []
array.sort()
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    if array[i] != array[i + 1]:
        list1.append(array[i])

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(list1[i])
```

Comment: What happens when `i` is equal to `len(array) - 1`, in the last loop?

Comment: ```for i in range(len(list1)):``` if you just want to print the elements, don't do that. Instead, do ```for i in list1:```

Comment: if last two values are same it will not show if i do len (array) -1

Comment: it show the error in first loop 2nd loop work correctly

Comment: You need to iterate ```for i in range(0, len(array)-1):``` because when the last element is fetched, ```i+1``` no longer exists hence an index error

Comment: If you just want to remove duplicates there's a more simple way: ```list1 = list(set(list1))```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the order, you can convert it to a `set` and the back to `list` like this :

```
array = [1, 22, 22, 3, 14, 14, 24, 5]
array = list(set(array))
print(array)
```

output: `[1, 3, 5, 14, 22, 24]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate ove length of the list - 1.

When the loop reaches the last element of the list, `i+1` is not even there. And you are trying to fetch an element which is not there, or the elements doesn't exist in the list.

So it raises and error.

You should do

```
array = [1, 22, 22, 3, 14, 14, 24, 5]
j = 0
i = 0
list1 = []
array.sort()
for i in range(0, len(array)-1):
    if array[i] != array[i + 1]:
        list1.append(array[i])

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(list1[i])
```

However there are other alternatives too.

Example

```
array = [1, 22, 22, 3, 14, 14, 24, 5]
arr=list(set(array))
```

Or you can use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
array = [1, 22, 22, 3, 14, 14, 24, 5]
arr=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(array))
```